# Multilevel Inheritance Generics and Spring Issue - Java

Tags: java, spring, generics, software-design

I have the following scenario:

Pojos:

```
abstract class A

abstract class B1 extends A
class C1 extends B1 
         
abstract class B2 extends A
class C2 extends B2
```

Engines:

```
abstract class EngineA<A> {
    private EngineA a;
          
    public EngineA(A a) {
           this.a = a;
    }
}

abstract class EngineB1<B1> extends EngineA<B1> {
    private EngineB1 b1;
              
    public EngineB1(B1 b1) {
        super(b1);
        this.b1 = b1;
    }
}

class EngineC1 extends EngineB1<C1> // similar constructor

abstract class EngineB2<B2> extends EngineA<B2> // similar constructor
class EngineC2 extends EngineB2<C2> // similar constructor
```

All Pojos and Engines are Component with scope prototype

I have done all this in order to achieve :

```
EngineA engineA = context.getBean(EngineA.class, /*either C1 or C2 object */)
```

in `main()`.

If the object is C1, I want it to be used by EngineC1 and C2 for EngineC2;
so that if any classes are to be added in the future, I don't have to change the main method. I also don't want to check `instanceof` or use `Qualifier` because it will ultimately lead to a code change of `main` in addition to the classes (I guess).

But I am getting this error:

```
No qualifying bean of type `EngineA1` available: expected single matching bean but found 2: c1, c2.
```

First of all is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

Are the generics written correctly?

One of the possible solutions is to build my own `EngineFactory` using Reflection. But is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I cant find built-in Spring method for this purpose (checked 3.0.6.RELEASE).
Here is the way that can be implemented, hope this will be helpful

```
package pt;

public class Tc {

    // Type Classes
    public static abstract class A{}

    public static abstract class B1 extends A{}
    public static abstract class B2 extends A{}

    public static abstract class C1 extends B1{}
    public static abstract class C2 extends B2{}

    // Engine Classes
    public static abstract class EngineA<T extends A>{}

    public static abstract class EngineB1<T extends B1> extends EngineA<B1>{}
    public static abstract class EngineB2<T extends B2> extends EngineA<B2>{}

    public static class EngineC1 extends EngineB1<C1>{}
    public static class EngineC2 extends EngineB2<C2>{}

}
```

Spring Config file: paramType.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="c1" class="pt.Tc$EngineC1"/>
    <bean id="c2" class="pt.Tc$EngineC2"/>

    <bean id="beanUtil" class="pt.BeanUtil"/>

</beans>
```

BeanUtil Class handling the purpose:

```
package pt;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class BeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass, Class... paramClasses) {

        List<String> expectedSet = convertToClassNameList(paramClasses);

        Map<String, T> beansOfType = context.getBeansOfType(beanClass);

        for (T value : beansOfType.values()) {

            Type type = value.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            if (!(type instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
                continue;
            }

            ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
            List<String> currentParamList = convertToClassNameList(parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments());
            if (isSameListContent(currentParamList, expectedSet)) {
                return value;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isSameListContent(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        if (list1.size() != list2.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            if (!list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected List<String> convertToClassNameList(Type... paramTypes) {
        List<String> retval = new ArrayList<String>(paramTypes.length);
        for (Type type : paramTypes) {
            // class java.lang.String
            retval.add(type.toString().substring(6));
        }
        return retval;
    }

    protected List<String> convertToClassNameList(Class... paramClasses) {
        List<String> retval = new ArrayList<String>(paramClasses.length);
        for (Class clazz : paramClasses) {
            retval.add(clazz.getName());
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
package pt;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:paramType.xml"})
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    BeanUtil beanUtil;

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test1() {

        Tc.EngineA bean = beanUtil.getBean(Tc.EngineA.class, Tc.C1.class);
        System.out.println("Found Instance for param (pt.Tc$EngineC1) --> " + bean.getClass().getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(bean.getClass(), Tc.EngineC1.class);

        bean = beanUtil.getBean(Tc.EngineA.class, Tc.C2.class);
        System.out.println("Found Instance for param (pt.Tc$EngineC2) --> " + bean.getClass().getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(bean.getClass(), Tc.EngineC2.class);

        bean = beanUtil.getBean(Tc.EngineA.class, Tc.B2.class);
        System.out.println("Not existing param type --> " + (bean == null ? "Success" : "Fail"));
        Assert.assertNull(bean);
    }
}
```

Result is:

```
Found Instance for param (pt.Tc$EngineC1) --> pt.Tc$EngineC1
Found Instance for param (pt.Tc$EngineC2) --> pt.Tc$EngineC2
Not existing param type --> Success
```

Comment: In this scenario the class Tc will have to be updated whenever new pojos and engines are added which i dont want. Anyways thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Using Tc class is just for grouping. Nothing related with logic. Try seperating each as different files and you'll see it'll work too. So any classes can be added freely later on.